# It's possible to disable checkout file function on Visual Studio Community 2015/17 and VS Team Services

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I work in a scenario where a small team (3 people) need to work in a same project. But would happen me and my coworkers need to work on the same file.

Question, Is it possible setup a scenario like that? Or I need to look for ohter paying solution?

Comment: What is the scenario? Please elaborate on that. Without more detail on what you are specifically trying to accomplish and cannot, despite what you've tried (elaborate on that too). The only real answer to your question is that with source control you can do pretty much whatever you want.

Comment: For example, instead to make a merge of a edit file by 2 developers. Create a condition that if a developer 1 is editing a file. Developer 2 can´t edit the file because it is locked for developer 1.

Comment: Ummm, it seems you are asking "Can source control software do what source control software does if I ask it to do what it can do?". Which of course the answer is, yes. What maybe you are asking is can I have locks on files I checkout, so others cannot commit against them before I release those locks and allow them? If so, yes (sort of/depends/give-it-a-try), if you configure it that way. (see Daniel Mann's answer below). Regardless, this is not an issue where "buying" a better tool is going to make any difference for you.The free stuff you are using does what you want. If you tell it to do it.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue by Daniel's answer? any update?

Answer (score 0):

This is **not recommended**, but you can enable [exclusive checkouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/understand-lock-types) on files if you're using server workspaces.

Exclusive checkouts are a legacy left behind by antiquated version control systems that aren't capable of handling multiple checkouts. There is no reason to use them in a modern VCS.